# kendoFilter with multiple filter values

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-multiselect

In the kendoGrid, you can implement the [Filter Multi Checkboxes](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes) in order of specify multiple values for a single column filter.

I would like to replicate the same feature inside the kendoFilter widget.  I've tried to use a kendoMultiSelect as an editorTemplate (see this [Dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EXUqohUt/5))

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 20,
        data: products,
        autoSync: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ProductID",
                fields: {
                    ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    ProductName: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#filter").kendoFilter({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        applyButton: true,
        fields: [
            { name: "ProductName", label: "Product Name", editorTemplate: productDropDownEditor },
        ],
        expression: {
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: "ProductName", value: "", operator: "eq" }
            ]
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        columns: [
            { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" }
        ]
    });
});

function productDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-bind="value: value" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        //.kendoDropDownList({
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "ProductName",
            dataValueField: "ProductName",
            autoclose: false,
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Unfortunately, I think it doesn't work because the [filter.value](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter#filter.value) doesn't expect an array as a parameter.  Is there a standard way to use the tell the kendoFilter how to create a filter based on multiple values?

Comment: Your Dojo example is showing empty for me...

Comment: Indeed... I fixed the example url.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do. Unfortunately, you can't use it that way because `kendoFilter` does it one by one (i.e. you'll need to click on the "+" icon in order to add another filter). Here is another alternative of what I think you are trying to do.

First off, I'd hide `kendoFilter`. Then based on the multiselected product name I'd redo the expression of the filter. This still accomplishes what you are trying to do (filtering through multiselect). Try the code below in the DOJO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/filter/custom-editors">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.default-ocean-blue.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="../content/shared/js/products.js"></script>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="filter"></div>
        <div id="multiselect"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    pageSize: 20,
                    data: products,
                    autoSync: true,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductID",
                            fields: {
                                ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                ProductName: { validation: { required: true } }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });

                var filter = $("#filter").kendoFilter({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    expression: {
                        logic: "or",
                        filters: [],
                    }
                }).data("kendoFilter");

                $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataTextField: "ProductName",
                    dataValueField: "ProductName",
                    autoclose: false,
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                        }
                    },
                    change: function(e) {
                        var dataItems = e.sender.dataItems();
                        var options = filter.getOptions();
                        options.expression.filters = [];
                        for (let dataItem of dataItems) {
                            options.expression.filters.push({
                                field: "ProductName",
                                value: dataItem.ProductName,
                                operator: "eq"
                            });
                        }

                        filter.setOptions(options);
                        filter.applyFilter();
                    }
                });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                        { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #filter {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```